# Define the direction of a bullet given the orientation of the cannon

Tags: swift, vector, sprite-kit, angle

I'm having the player to control the rotation of a spaceship in a 2D environment (similar to Asteroids game) through its zRotation value. I'm then trying to make the missiles to be continuously shot in the direction the spaceship is facing, so I tried to apply the impulse to the projectile giving it this vector:

`CGVector(dx: sin(player.zRotation), dy: cos(player.zRotation))`

since the zRotation is returning a value in radians. It works fine in the 1st and 2nd quadrants (imagine the x from 0 to 180 in a cartesian axis system) but it messes up in the other two and I can't figure out why - the missiles begin to be shot in the wrong directions. Am I missing something important? Every answer will be appreciated.

EDIT: I have already found a decent amount of similar questions but none of them were actually helpful to solve my troubles. Here I'm not considering other params like the touch coordinates or the enemy (x,y) position to determine the bullet trajectory; my spaceship is supposed to simply shoot in front of it, detecting the angle of its orientation and firing accordingly.

EDIT #2: I just figured out there is a different way to achieve this which is apparently working fine. Given the SAME EXACT vector:

`let vector = CGVector(dx: sin(player.zRotation), dy: cos(player.zRotation))`

I simply tried to replace

`applyImpulse(vector)`

with:

`bullet.runAction(SKAction.moveBy(vector, duration: 2))`

although the firing was a bit weak so I fixed it by multiplying a 1000 on both the dx and the dy of the vector, and it works perfectly. This sounds a bit odd to me but I still don't understand why it didn't work using the physics engine...

Comment: Are you sure there is no gravity in your scene?

Comment: Yes. I mean, there is gravity in the scene, but both the player spaceship and the bullet have their `affectedByGravity` set to false.

Comment: Which direction does the cannon face when its `zRotation` is 0?

Comment: It is facing to the very North if we imagine it being the hand of a compass. I'm currently using the default "spaceship" image which comes along every new Spritekit project. I am running the game in landscape right, if it can be of any help, so the north I'm talking about is to be considered in a landscape orientation.

Comment: Added more informations.

Comment: Try adding `let angle = player.zRotation + CGFloat(M_PI_2)` and then set `let vector = CGVectorMake(cos(angle), sin(angle))`

Comment: It works fine as long as I keep shooting the missiles via the `moveBy` action, but it still messes up when trying the `applyForce` method...perhaps I am missing something important in setting the physic scene?